# Where is publish_post hook fired?

Tags: hooks, publish

Hook [publish_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post), which does not necessary need to be run on post publishing only, it can be used for any post type and any post status in this format {status}_{post_type} which also makes it hard to find in wordpress core

Does anyone know where it's fired exactly in wordpress core? It does not seem to be related to wp_insert_post because it's not called when this function is run

Comment: Have you read: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@shanebp](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/164145/where-is-publish-post-hook-fired/165153#comment237713_164145) suggested you in a comment to OP, that is one of the hook fired by the function [`wp_transition_post_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_transition_post_status/), it's a bit hard to find it doing a search in code because is a *dynamic* hook, in facts the line in code that fires it looks like:

```
do_action( "{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}", $post->ID, $post );
```

Where `$new_status` is the new status a post has after un update and `$post->post_type` is, as you can guess, the post type.

So the form `"publish_post"` is only one of possible hooks, fired when a post of standard post type has been published, to make an example same line in code will also fire `"trash_page"` when you delete a page, and so on.

As you can see in the [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_transition_post_status/#source-code) it is the last of status transition hooks being fired.

For the others and also for additional info look at [Post Status Transitions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) page in Codex.

If you mind have a look, the function `wp_transition_post_status` is called inside the  [`wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function, in current version at line [#3431 of `wp-includes/post.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post.php#L3431).

There you can see

```
if ( 'attachment' !== $postarr['post_type'] ) {
  wp_transition_post_status( $data['post_status'], $previous_status, $post );
}
```

making clear that function and related hooks aren't called for `'attachment'` post type.